# Average and sum of data of all mondays, tuesdays, etc in a month

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I have an excel document with a main sheet and 1 sheet for every day of the month.
Every month this excel document will be filled with data for each day.

The main sheet has to show the average and sum of the data of each weekday.

My problem is that every month the weekdays are on other days in the month, so I can't simply use the 1st day of the month for a monday.

I start with an empty Excel document with only the main sheet.
My VB6 program then adds the sheet for each monthday with the data.

I know how to fill the monthday sheets with data, but I don't know how to fill the cells in the main sheet with a formula.

The average and sum formula's in the main sheet have to be dynamic to chose which sheets are mondays, tuesday, etc.

Here are some simplified examples of the sheets of january and february:

[image: january][image: february]

The real monthday sheets contain much more data, and the main sheet more analyses. See below for a part of it:

[image: part of the real document]

I see various way to go for solving this:

- from my VB6 program
- via VBA in the excel document
- via a more complex excel formula
- having the main sheet in a separate document, while filling another excel document with the monthday data which can be accessed from the main sheet.

How can I make sure the cells in the main sheet always use the right weekday, or how can I from my VB6 program write a formula in the cells in the main sheet?

Comment: The "solution" I am thinking now is to make 35 subsheets for the data and leaving the first and last ones empty depending on the first monday and last sunday in the month ... it's not ideal, but at least I think i can make that work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you can, I suggest you change your workbook structure to use a [tidy data layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data), i.e. don't have separate sheets for each day but rather concatenate all your data and add a column for day of month. Then you can just use a single pivot table.

Failing that, make a column of numbers `1` to `31`, make a cell with the year and another with the month. Use `=DATE()` to make a cell of the dates for the month and then use `=WEEKDAY()` to get the week day for each month. In another column average and sum your data per day of month. then either use a pivot table or just `SUMIF` to aggregate this up to a day of week level.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The screendumps in my question were some simplified documents just highlighting the specific problem. I edited the question to add a screendump of the real document which shows only a part, there is much more to the right and bottom of it.

Comment: I now think a better option would be to put the data into a separate excel document, which i can fill from my vb6 program. And then retreive that data from another excel document with the main sheet. I haven't accessed other documents from excel yet though, so I will have to look into that.

Comment: I think it is always a bad idea to reference separate excel workbooks from a workbook as you great dependencies on things like file structure (folder names and locations) and the other file existing and not changing. I would recommend against this.

Comment: You can create separate sheets to act as "views" of a subset of the main data if needed.

Comment: @Dan I agree, that's why i had the data in sheet behind in the main sheet in the same document ... I just thought it through and the same problem remains with dynamic weekdays even when i load the data in a separate document.

Comment: @DaveInCaz : what do you mean? can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Hrqls I was thinking that having all the data in one worksheet might be useful for calculation / analysis purposes but isn't necessarily optimal for certain use cases of viewing the data or end results. One method to reconcile that could be to create new worksheets which refer back to to "master" data on the main sheet. Then the outputs can be organized however is needed without complicating the data processing.

Comment: @Hrqls No the same dependency problems won't apply, if everything is in one worksheet you can always depend on that worksheet working no matter where it is on your computer, no matter what other files exist on your computer, no matter what your files are named, no matter if you change sheet names etc. You are in control of how you create this spread sheet, do it in tidy form (long form) and use pivot tables if you want to report on the data. Anything else is just going to make analysis unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I see what you and Dan mean. That will definetly make it easier. I will just have think of a layout which doesn't scare the client by an overload of data.

Comment: @Dan I see you suggestion of a cell listing the weekday and the use of SUMIF ... my knowldge of Excel is limited, is there also an AVERAGEIF or can I count how many cells are used in the SUMIF so i can calculate my avaerage?

Comment: thanks! you set me on the right track .... and google provided me with more information : https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-start-using-countif-sumif-and-averageif-in-excel--cms-28086

Comment: @Hrqls yes there is an averageif. btw you might also need to use the `INDIRECT` function if you really really want to continue having one sheet per day as this function lets you index based on the contents of a cell (i.e. you can build the sheet names from the date in cells and use `INDIRECT` to index that specific sheet for your `SUMIF`. But I'm telling you, use long form data and if you want a nice view for your client use a pivot table with slicers.